# A script or a regular expression to remove all the print statements from the python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove all the print statements from my file. The task of manually erasing all the statements is exhausting. I want the print statements to be removed and not to be commented. I would like to execute this in python where I would just give the file name(file path)

Comment: `.*print\(.*` will capture whole lines that contain the string `print(` that should be safe enough to remove, alternatively you can add `print = lambda *args,**kwargs:None` on top of you script and local prints will do nothing

Comment: Are we talking about `print` statement or `print(...)` function? Removing the statement might be easier, as it has to be the first statement in the line (or after a `;` or `:`) whereas the `print` function could appear anywhere, or even be used by a different alias.

Comment: @Nullman Your reg ex will not catch multi line print statements or all lines after a print depending on if `re.MULTILINE` is used.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to do this? Is this some kind of Python 2-to-3 conversion? Or do you want to "silence" the `print`? In the latter case, it might be easier (and easily reversible) to re-define `print` (the function) to simply do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex - use this in your code and see if it works:

```
import re
str = 'print("dddd \" dddd")'
print(re.match(r"^\s*print\('.*'\)\s*$", str) or re.match(r'^\s*print\(".*"\)\s*$', str))
```

Replace the `str` above with `line` from within the file read loop suggested by `Pythia`.
Hope this helps (takes care of both `print('')` and `print("")`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try opening the file and then writing the lines which do not contain the print statement, something like:

```
with open("your_desired_file.extension", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("your_desired_file.extension", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if "print" not in line:
            f.write(line)
```

P.S.: as others have said, keep in mind this will 'delete' all lines which contain the string 'print', not only the statement or function, but even a comment. So be aware of that!

Comment: This will remove any line that contains the word 'print', including, but not limited to `# a comment about printing`, `"some string that says 'print'"`, and `not_the_print_function()`.

Comment: This is going to detect all uses of the word `print` and delete the line they appear on. Something more subtle is needed.

Comment: Well, you are right, but I intended to give solely an idea; it is quite 'brute' indeed.